# Joint PMF based on another variable's PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So there is this PMF of $M$ (a positive integer r.v) as follows:

$$p_M (m) = \frac13 \cdot  m \cdot  3^{-m}$$

with $m = {1,2,3,4,5,…}$

Another random variable N has a uniform PMF based on ${1,2,3,4,5,…,3m}$

what is $P_M,_N (m,n)$ and   $P_N(n)$?

I am not sure how to tackle this problem. I have calculated the values of $P_M(m)$: {0.11,0.074, 0.037, ... } , but then I got stuck. I am not sure how to proceed with the calculation of N. I thought I should divide each $P_M(m)$ with $3N$, but then I realized the value got so small I doubt it's the right way to do it.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: I think that $P_N(n)=\frac{1}{3n}$ as well.

Comment: As $N$ is a discrete uniform, you can write down $P_N(n)$ immediately. next you need to know the dependence structure of $M, N$. One special case is that they are independent, and in such case you can obtain the joint easily from the marginal pmf.

Comment: @BGM the dependence structure of $M, N$ is N's PMF is $1,2,3,..,3m$ as written above. But that's where I got confused, since $m$ has no limit, how am I supposed to know the range of $N$?

Comment: @callculus sorry it's supposed to be $3m$ instead of $3n$

Comment: @speedy_catch $$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} 1/3\cdot m\cdot 3^{-m}=\frac14$$. It should be $1$.

Comment: @callculus, and how do I relate $m$ to get $n$ and the marginal pmf?

Comment: Since the pdf is not valid I wouldn´t go on.

Comment: I guess the second part is mentioning about the conditional distribution of $N|M = m$. The joint pmf is just the product of the conditional pmf and the marginal pmf. But as callculus pointed out, you need to fix the given marginal pmf first.